# Animating Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I am using the bootstrap `glyphicon-triangle-left` and `glyphicon-triangle-bottom` glyphicons in a bootstrap accordion. When you open up a div it shows the `bottom` one and when you close it, it shows the `left` one.

When the icons switch classes it looks a little stupid so I want to create a transition maybe make the icon rotate or fade out/in.
But I am not sure how I can do this since I toggle between classes via jQuery like so:

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    jQuery(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find("i.indicator")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon-triangle-left');
    }
```

I am not sure how I can do this because it uses the classes from the bootstrap accordion etc.

I've tried doing something like this in my css file but it's not really doing what I want it to do :p

```
.glyphicon-triangle-bottom{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.glyphicon-triangle-left{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Anyone had any idea how I can make the icons transition?
Many thanks in advance!!

EDIT: I customized this code a bit but this a good representation of what my accordion looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your HTML is appreciated!

Comment: @urbz I've tried making one but I can't seem to replicate my situation since I use bootstrap and the chevron accordion doesn't want to work

Comment: @urbz I customized this code a bit but this is a good representation of my accordion http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding a new glyphicon you can rotate the existing left one to bottom.

Like this:

```
.glyphicon-triangle-left{
    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}
.glyphicon-triangle-left.rotate-90{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Then toggle the `rotate-90` class on click.

Updated the OP [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/3548/)

Comment: Was about to post the same. Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/guNcg9PY5SS4J8Bw1QrN?p=preview

Comment: For some reason my icon dissapears :o

Answer (score 1):

See this mashup of the info above.  I think it is what you are looking for if you are dealing with a bootstrap accordian.

[Working Accordion JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brass_anglo/tbsc2wdk/)

updated js to

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find("i.indicator")
        .toggleClass('rotate-180');
}
$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

and css to

```
.glyphicon-chevron-down{
  transition:transform 180ms ease-in;
}
.glyphicon-chevron-down.rotate-180{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition:transform 180ms ease-in;
}
.glyphicon-chevron-up{
  transition:transform 180ms ease-in;
}
.glyphicon-chevron-up.rotate-180{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
```